# Django - how to create duplicate apps without duplicating the code (models, signals and so on)

Tags: django, models

This may be a weird question, and from the title it may not be obvious, but couldn't find out a better / more descriptive title for my questions.

I have an inventory control app, with own models, signals, admin, and forms. I need to duplicate this app for multiple companies, and below is what I am currently doing:

```
app_shared
    models
        products
        adressbook
    forms
    signals
    admin

app_company1
    models
        inventory
        transactions
        ...
    forms
    signals
    admin

app_company2
    models
        inventory
        transactions
        ...
    forms
    signals
    admin
```

The issue is, between app_company1 and app_company2, everything is identical, same exact models, signals and so on. I have to keep them separate to create their own tables in database. But don't want to duplicate same code. Is there a way of preventing the duplication?

Comment: Put the code at common place and just import and add into each project. That is how other 3rdpaty apps are used.

Comment: if you do this, than it uses the tables generated in common app, does not create separate ones for each app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move all the identical code to the `app_shared` application and import it from `app_company1` and `app_company2`.

If have separate tables in the DB is a requirement, then the `inventory` and `transaction` models should be defined as abstract in `app_shared`. `app_company1` and `app_company2` should create their own corresponding models that derive from the abstract models. This will ensure separate tables are generated in the DB. See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) documentation page for more details.

Comment: Seems this is what i need. But now having issue with foreign keys: Assume there is foreign key relations between inventory and transactions tables (inventory table has a field trans= models.ForeignKey(transaction, null=True, blank=True)). When I create them as abstract classes in app_shared, it complains due to foreign keys. Isn't it possible to have foreign keys between abstract classes?

Comment: A solution I've used in a similar situation was to use Generic relations (see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) documentation page). It's cumbersome but it does the job.

Comment: In the documentation, couldn't see anything about defining Generic relations. Please help.

Comment: My bad. Provided the wrong link. Sorry. Here's the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) to the Generic relations documentation.

Comment: looks really cumbersome :(. May prefer duplicating the model code.. :(((  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You could make the models abstract, as OrenD said, but leave out the foreignkeys. Then just duplicate the foreignkeys in the derived models.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is, between app_company1 and app_company2, everything is identical, same exact models, signals and so on. I have to keep them separate to create their own tables in database. But don't want to duplicate same code. Is there a way of preventing the duplication?

If you have such code then your design of apps is not perfect. You can try to make one app for `app_company` and try to distinguish between records of different companies. That way you can add as many companies as you want without duplicating the code or adding new app for each one of them.

Comment: there is a reason to keep company db tables separate. So this doesn't solve my problem.